# Термины в программировании

Tags: терминология

Я совсем недавно начал учить программирование и мне часто встречаются такие термины как "devopler", "user" и тд. Хотел узнать практически все термины в программировании и их значение.

> P.S.Пожалуйста напишите подробно

Comment: "Хотел узнать практически все термины в программировании и их значение." - в этом и состоит суть многолетнего обучения, узнать и осознать много много терминов. В каждой области Вы будете находить множество новых.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1267

Comment: Ну выучите вы термины и что дальше, программистом станете? Мало просто термины выучить, надо понимать как они работают, а это только практика

Answer (score 2):

Практически все термины в программировании - это профессиональный жаргон + иронический эрратив. Чтобы понимать термины, достаточно иметь словарную базу английского языка, что достигается практикой чтения англоязычных текстов по специальности.

Работа современного программиста теснейшим образом связана с изучением документации, так что просто решая какие-то задачи вы повышаете свой `скилл` (*получите англицизм*) и смежные навыки.

В некоторых случаях, наблюдается столкновение русскоязычных терминов и англицизмов вроде:

thread - поток - нить

application - приложение - аппликация

Первая колонка - англоязычный термин, вторая - русский устоявшийся, третья - англицизм, буквальный перевод с английского.

Третья колонка появилась в результате деятельности `копирайтеров` (*вот вам еще один англицизм*) без профильного образования в `IT` (*ну вы поняли*), которые переводили специальные термины "в лоб". Собственно, использование терминов из второй колонки и выдает отсутствие профильного образования, полученного в России. Так могут выражаться носители английского языка, например, которые выучили немножко русского языка, и это *не совсем корректно*.

Сама задача изучения терминов имеет смысл в том случае, если вы лингвист и изучаете профессиональный жаргон. Для программиста изучение терминов происходит автоматически в процессе профессионального общения с коллегами. Да, чтение статей и документации - это тоже общение, только заочное.

Comment: `thread - поток - нить` - тред

Comment: `В некоторых случаях, наблюдается столкновение русскоязычных терминов и англицизмов вроде:` - бывают коллизии (столкновения) перевода, типа thread - поток и stream - поток, при том что значения совершенно разные.

Comment: @insolor - это уже другой род проблем. В таком случае, или понятно из контекста, о каком потоке речь, или уточняют - поток ввода-вывода, поток выполнения.

Answer (score 0):

Практически все термины выучить сложновато будет, но для общего развития знать не помешает. Я бы советовал использовать гугл и искать все термины там. Но так же можно воспользоваться [англоязычным источником](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/program.htm). Где указывается например, что developer:

> A developer is an individual who is responsible for creating or
> working on the development of a product or service. Most developers
> utilize one or more programming languages to develop their product or
> service. They may work alone or on a team, and may develop part of or
> all a product or service. Companies like Microsoft and Oracle employ
> many developers, due to the complexity of the products and services
> they develop and sell to customers.

Так же вот [ссылка](https://www.webopedia.com/Programming) на такого рода источник